# Which one to choose waitpid/wait/waitid?

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait, waitpid

I want to use execl in child process after doing fork. execl will execute the script which will take around 120 seconds of time. I tried almost all the combination with waitpid, wait and waitid with different argument (0, WNOHANG, etc.,) but in all case I am getting -1 return value. So I want to know in which wait function I need to use when? So I can concentrate in one wait function to make it work.

One more interesting thing which I observed from my logs is that when I am doing nothing in child process it is showing my parent thread as orphaned. I don't know how it is possible? How can my parent thread become orphaned?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t Checksum_pid = fork();

    if (Checksum_pid < 0)
        printf("Fork Failed\n");
    else if (Checksum_pid == 0)
    {
        execl("/bin/ls","ls",(char *)NULL) ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        int childStatus;
        pid_t returnValue = waitpid(Checksum_pid, &childStatus, 0);

        if (returnValue > 0)
        {
            if (WIFEXITED(childStatus))
                printf("Exit Code: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(childStatus));

        }
        else if (returnValue == 0)
            printf("Child process still running\n");
        else
        {
            if (errno == ECHILD)
                printf(" Error ECHILD!!\n");
            else if (errno == EINTR)
                printf(" Error EINTR!!\n");
            else
                printf("Error EINVAL!!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any of them will do. You're doing something wrong somewhere. For further help, post your code and explanation of what you observe-

Comment: Maybe your test for whether you are the child or the parent is the wrong way round. Show us your code.

Comment: Look at `errno` e.g. using `perror` when a `wait*` function gives -1.

Comment: If you get a -1 return value, inspect `errno`, or use `perror` to print the error message.

Comment: I am getting ECHILD as errno.

Comment: Your last `else` should call `perror`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented: your last `else` should just be

```
 else perror("waitpid");
```

But you are getting `ECHILD`. So please read [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) man page:

> ```
>    ECHILD (for wait()) The calling process does not have any unwaited-
>           for children.
>
>   ECHILD (for waitpid() or waitid()) The process specified by pid
>           (waitpid()) or idtype and id (waitid()) does not exist or is
>           not a child of the calling process.  (This can happen for
>           one's own child if the action for SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN.
>           See also the Linux Notes section about threads.)
> ```

BTW, I cannot reproduce your error. Check also your limits as given by `ulimit -a` on bash.

Maybe your `execl` fails (especially if you execute some script instead of `/bin/ls`). Add a call to `perror` after it.

Also, compile with `gcc -Wall -g`  and use `strace` and `gdb`

Comment: I used strerror(errno) in printf. I am getting String "No Child Process" from strerror with (-1 return value from waitpid). When Child is running, I am getting String "Succuss" from strerror with 0 as return value from waitpid.